# What is the exact difference between SAMLp and WS-Trust?

Tags: web-application, authentication, federation, identity

They seem to be similar on the surface, but I'm not sure how deep the differences are.

Can someone explain to me the difference between SAMLp and WS-Trust?  ADFSv2 gives me a choice between these options and I'm not sure which to choose.

Comment: Read http://www.terena.org/activities/tf-emc2/meetings/9/slides/SAML&WS.ppt

Answer (score 7):

WSTrust is a standard which is specifies how to encrypt/decrypt/sign SOAP messages and how to bind security tokens to a SOAP message.

SAML tokens are an example of a security token that could be bound to a SOAP message.

The SAML protocol provides a standard way to acquire, release and renew SAML tokens using SSL to protect communications and the XmlDsig standard to protect the token.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, They are similar WRT the end-goal.

- WS-Trust is SOAP-based involving front-channel (browser) and back-channel (among services) communication, SAML-Passive can optionally use SOAP for backchannel communication,
- SAML-P can involve no backchannel at all.
- The XML documents involved have different name spaces: WST vs SAML
- SAML-P is the name for the process of redirection and communication 
  that achieves the federated login goal using SAML docs, but it seems
  that 'SAML' has come to be synonymous with 'SAML-Passive'